# watchKit console logs showing, but not iOS application?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

Currently my console log only shows watchKit app NSLogs but not the iOS app one's. This is on the simulator. If I run only the iOS app, the logs are printed on the console, so I know the code is working. Is there some setting I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

It can.
Run WatchKit App first, then run iPhone App later.
You will see drop-down list top of output window(Debug area).
The drop-down list can select which app to show console messages.
Open another source code editor window by double click some source code file.
You also see drop-down list too.
Select Watch one of them, and iPhone another.
Finally you can see both logs from Watch and iPhone same time in different windows.

Tested : XCode 7.1 AppStore version

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to either debug the watch or the iOS app.